# Why does this call to update the email subject return an error?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign C# SDK for the REST API.  Calling the EnvelopesApi.Update() method to change the email subject on an envelope.

My testers are reporting an *occasional* error:

**Error calling Update: { "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER", "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Value for 'status' must be 'created', 'sent' or 'voided'." }**

I'm reusing the current values from the `GetEnvelope` call, so my guess is the status isn't in the proper state, but they report that the envelope has not been signed yet.  Should I set the status to 'sent'? I ONLY want to update the email subject and message.  Is it possibly because I'm nulling the purge state?  Is this the wrong way to update the email subject and message?

```
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();

        Envelope envelope = envelopesApi.GetEnvelope(AccountId, envelopeId);
        envelope.EmailSubject = emailSubject;
        envelope.EmailBlurb = emailMessage;
        envelope.PurgeState = null;

        var updateOptions = new EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions { resendEnvelope = "true" };

        var updateSummary = envelopesApi.Update(AccountId, envelopeId, envelope, updateOptions);
```

Comment: I do agree you can change the email subject via an envelope correct action - the envelope will need to be in a sent state though. If you are seeing this occasionally, then perhaps you are trying to make this call against envelopes which are completed/declined/expired. Can you double check ?

Comment: @LuisScott I'll double check tomorrow.  My thought is maybe the state is "delivered" or some other state (other than created/sent/voided) that I would think should still allow email subject/blurb edits.  I could set the status to sent in the call but that field is not what I want to edit.

Comment: Sent and delivered are decently analogous. Sent means the recipient has yet to open the envelope in DocuSign, delivered means that the recipient has opened and accepted the eDisclosure step. IMO both are eligible for correction.

Comment: Okay I was able to figure it out.  It happens as we said, where the state is "delivered" and when you make the call to .update it apparently requires "created", "sent", or "voided" in the status field.  I guess changing it back to "sent" from delivered may make sense since i am resending it...  Perhaps I should contact docusign to guarantee..

Answer (score 0):

When the envelope's status changes to "delivered" (after all recipient's have viewed the document), the call to `.update` fails.  It is as the error says, the status must be 'sent', 'created', or 'voided'.  So you must update the status along with the email and subject.

I can't say if this is appropriate for everyone's use-case but it seems to make sense.